# jQuery toggle, display animation and load url

Tags: jquery

I started learning php and smarty few months ago, all is going good so far. 
Now I came to the point where I need to use jQuery.

I have a list of articles which I want to load into div without reloading the page.
This is my html/smarty code:

```
<a class="title" id="link_{$val.id}" href="#id{$val.id}" onclick="load('{$baseurl}/read-{$val.id}.html');return false;">{$val.title}</a>
   <div id="loadingDiv_{$val.id}" style="display:none">
      <img src="{$templatepath}/images/loading.gif" />
   </div>
   <div id="Loaded_{$val.id}" class="full-article"> </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click on link, I want the `<div id="loadingDiv">` to toggle down displaying my loading animation while the page is being loaded and when it's ready I want the animation to go away and load the content of my page into my `<div id="Loaded_{$val.id}"></div>`. 
When my visitors finish reading chosen article, I want them to be able to click on that link again and toggle the `<div id="Loaded_{$val.id}"></div>` up.

I've been looking for hours now and can't get it to work.
I tried using this

```
<script>
function load(url){
   var target = event.target.id;
   $("#Loaded_"+target).toggle();
   $("#Loaded_"+target).load(url);   
}
</script>
```

and it kinda works but there are 3 major problems with my code:

- it toggles down, loads the page into div but when I click the link again it toggles up and loads the page again so every toggle down and toggle up adds 2 views to my article
- it works in chrome but doesn't work in firefox

> --
>   ReferenceError: event is not defined

- can't get the loading animation to show

I'm not looking for complete solution, I would like to know which functions do I need to use/combine to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- for the first point, why not just check if the div already contains
  the content?
- for the second point, better to use an
  [`onClick`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event listener so the event
  gets passed
- for the third point, you can start your handler by
  showing the `loadingDiv`

all together now:

```
<a class="title" id="link_{$val.id}" href="#id{$val.id}" 
   data-url="{$baseurl}/read-{$val.id}.html">{$val.title}</a>
   <div id="loadingDiv_{$val.id}" style="display:none">
      <img src="{$templatepath}/images/loading.gif" />
   </div>
<div id="Loaded_{$val.id}" class="full-article"> </div>



$('a.title').on('click', function() {   // use a click listener
       var target = this.id;

       $("#loadingDiv_"+target).show(); // display loading image

       $("#Loaded_"+target).toggle();
       if ($("#Loaded_"+target).html()){         // only load if the container 
           var url = getAttribute("data-url");   // has no content yet
           $("#Loaded_"+target).load(url);   
       }

       $("#loadingDiv_"+target).hide(); // dismiss the loading image
});
```

Comment: Thanks jbr3zy, toggles down, displays my loading animation but doesn't load the page and doesn't toggle up if clicked again.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined`
 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Comment: edited my answer based on @adeneo's suggestion. what version of jQuery are you using? should be 1.7.2+

Comment: 1.10.2.min.js
After applying your changes the only error I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: getAttribute is not defined` but I'll try to figure it out, you and adeneo helped me enough :) thanks again

Comment: Got it all working :) I ended up using ajaxStop to hide the loading animaion. Could you take a look at my code and just tell me if it's valid?
http://pastebin.com/9YCdnjQe

Answer (score 1):

First remove the inline event handlers :

```
<a class="title" id="link_{$val.id}" href="#id{$val.id}" data-url="{$baseurl}/read-{$val.id}.html">{$val.title}</a>
<div id="loadingDiv_{$val.id}" style="display:none">
    <img src="{$templatepath}/images/loading.gif" />
</div>
<div id="Loaded_{$val.id}" class="full-article"> </div>
```

Then use proper event handlers, and set a class once the content is loaded:

```
$('a.title').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $('#Loaded' + this.id);

    if ( ! elem.hasClass('loaded') ) {
        elem.load( elem.data('url') );
    }

    elem.toggle().addClass('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Now it toggles down and up nicely but it doesn't load the page into div.